# How to determine cpu required

Tags: extjs, dojo, xpages, xenapp

We have domino xpages application running in xenapp 6.5 environment. The citrix machine is 64 bit 2 proc 16 GB running on windows 2008.  Lotus notes client version is 8.5.2 and the xpages use embedded firefox browser.

While opening the xpage it takes nearly 100% cpu for just 2 concurrent users. The free memory availbale at that time was 10 to 11 GB. We are expecting about 30 users on one citrix box but it fails when we add 3rd concurrent user.

This xpages application make several rest service calls to pull data from domino back end to populate extjs grid.  It also loads extjs, dojo and jquery frameworks. From IE Network summary the app received about 386kb and sent 59kb.

It works ok when tried in local workstation but on citrix where we expect more than 30 users the cpu seem fall way short.  May be its the application issue that it consumes so much processing but is there a way to determine how much CPU would be required if the citrix environment need to handle 30 users. 
Appreciate help.

Comment: It's not normal, your environment should easily support such load. This seems like a very specific case. Make sure you have installed Lotus Notes properly as IBM advised and create a service request.

Comment: Wild wild guess: high CPU often occurs when data can't be read/written fast enough. Virtual configurations are very suspectible to that. Check the disk io wait queue. Fix it and CPU will go down. We generally have an obsession with CPU (~ horse powers of a car) not realizing that traffic congestion (I/O) is the limiting factor. A Ferrari miles per gallon sucks when stuck in a traffic jam

Comment: it seems to be more complex problem, not only CPU: my guess is ineffective work with indexes/views

Comment: This is in test environment right now with not lot of data.  So I am not quite sure if this has anything to do with lotus notes db (like views/indexes) but will look into that.  Can poor application design/coding cause this issue? We are going to open a service ticket with IBM and see what they say.  Will also seek some help with revisiting virtual configurations.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: @lense “Can poor application design/coding cause this issue?” since you’ve mentioned this thing is using at least 3 different libraries, I can basically guarantee you that your issue is bad application design/coding.

Comment: Anything can be the reason. Once I have experienced a similar problem on non-supported Terminal Services environment. The first five user was hitting 10% CPU but when the sixth person launches Notes, CPU spike was hitting 100% and eventually crashing the OS. After a while we noticed "Timer" component in the notes was buggy. Removing fixed the problem. Keep testing with smaller and simpler parts of your code.

Comment: @C Snover -  we started with dojo that comes with notes.  But then there are quite a number of grid functionalities tha extjs seem to be better at.  But we couldn't get completely off of dojo.  And since anyway its not going to load everything we didn't make too much effort.  So its two libraries and jquery for some of the ease of use it offers.  Understand its not the best design but sticking with just one library isn't helping to meet all the need. @Serdar Basegmez - Tried just one web service call and that seem to result in 40% spike in cpu.

Comment: Watch your io from the Domino perspective. Not the part on the network. The disk io. Easy to get that wrong in a virtual environment